# Modify order of column in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with a 2D numpy array like this:

```
array = np.asarray([[1,1,1,1,1],
                    [2,2,2,2,2],
                    [3,3,3,3,3],
                    [4,4,4,4,4], 
                    [5,5,5,5,5]])
```

I also have a 1D containing indexes to change the order of the columns of my first array.
So with this index array:

```
column_order = np.asarray([3,2,1,0,4])
```

I should have someting like this:

```
[[4 4 4 4 4]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [5 5 5 5 5]]
```

This is my code:

```
array = np.asarray([[1,1,1,1,1],
                    [2,2,2,2,2],
                    [3,3,3,3,3],
                    [4,4,4,4,4], 
                    [5,5,5,5,5]])

column_order = np.asarray([3,2,1,0,4])

new_array = np.copy(array)

for idx , i in enumerate(column_order):
    new_array[i] = array[idx]

print(new_array)
```

The problem is that it is a bit slow on large size array.
I would like to know if there is most efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Check [numpy integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Comment: Just `new_array=array[column_order]` should work.